# Unable to extract value from table after update query fired in android

Tags: android, sqlite

Nothing to display when click bookmark button. something wrong with this code.

first I have  set 1 value of bookmark where default value is 0. just like this
Here table name is Test.

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public Cursor bookmarkedJok(int i) {
    Cursor c = null;
        String Query = "UPDATE Test SET isBookmarked =1  WHERE _id = " + i ;
        c = myDataBase.rawQuery(Query, null);
         return c;
}
```

I am thinking , I am wrong with above query or related to below calling function.
In **first.java** where I am trying to bookmark, this code on onCreate of this

```
 DatabaseHelper db;
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                String i = cur.getString(cur
                                        .getColumnIndex("_id"));
                                int it=Integer.parseInt(i);

                               db.bookmarkedJok(it);
                            }
                        })
```

Now if i have no errors then i display this bookmared where value of isBookmarked is 1. 
**Second.java**

```
protected SQLiteDatabase db;
protected Cursor cursor;
protected ListAdapter adapter;
```

....

```
private void bookmark() {
    String[] fields = new String[] { "substr(title,1,23)",
            "substr(body,1,35)" };
    int[] views = new int[] { R.id.titleJok, R.id.bodyJok, };
    cursor = db
            .rawQuery(
                    "SELECT _id, substr(title,1,23),substr(body,1,35) FROM Test WHERE isBookmarked=" +1,
                    null);
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.book_list_item,
            cursor, fields, views);
    jokesList.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

please response me, what is the errors of my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How can you update record using rawQuery()?
try as below:

```
private SQLiteDatabase sqd;
public SQLiteDatabase create_database(String dbname)
  {
      try{
      sqd= SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("/data/data/Your packagename/databases/"+dbname,null);
      }catch(Exception e){
        e.getmessage();
              }
      }

   public void bookmarkedJok(int i) {
   //Cursor c = null;
   create_database(dbname);
    String Query = "UPDATE Test SET isBookmarked =1  WHERE _id = " + i ;
    sqd.execSQL(Query);
    // return c;
 }

 May this help you.
```

Comment: Oh it is really gr8 but when putting your code, i am getting this android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: attempt to write a readonly database: UPDATE jokes SET isBookmarked =1  WHERE _id = 4, So if you want more solution for this. plz reply.